# cakephp, obfuscate,hash, form ids

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, obfuscation

Question:
I am using cakephp and the form helper

My form looks like this

```
                 <?= $form->create(info );?>
                <?= $form->input('FirstOwner.fname');?>
                <?= $form->input('FirstOwner.lname');?>
                <?= $form->input('FirstOwner.first_owner_title');?>
                <?= $form->input('FirstOwner.first_owner_precentage');?>
                <?= $form->input('FirstOwner.first_home_address');?>
                <?= $form->input('FirstOwner.first_owner_city');?>
                <?= $form->input('FirstOwner.first_owner_state');?>
                <?= $form->input('FirstOwner.first_owner_zip');?>
   <?= $form->end(); ?>
```

The html output is

```
<div class="input text"><label for="FirstOwnerFname">Fname</
label><input name="data[FirstOwner][fname]" type="text"
maxlength="255" value="" id="FirstOwnerFname" /></div>           <div
class="input text"><label for="FirstOwnerLname">Lname</label><input
name="data[FirstOwner][lname]" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""
id="FirstOwnerLname" /></div>
```

how can i obfuscate/hash the id name and id?

I want it to produces something like

```
<div class="input text"><label for="FirstOwnerFname">Fname</
label><input name="5sdf65sf6g56asdf56as" type="text" maxlength="255"
value="" id="asd45a5sd4a5sd45ad" /
```

Comment: What kind of an attack are you trying to prevent by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Create the elements yourself using `$form->hidden()`, `$form->text()`, etcetera. Then you have control over the fieldnames. But you will manually need to translate them back in your controller before saving.

But... why are you doing this? Not security-by-obscurity I hope?

Comment: that was the idea, security by obscurity. is that not a good idea?

Comment: @john No, it never is. Also, what's the point? There's still going to be a label associated with the field that tells a human what the field is for. The field name may be obfuscated, but the same information is still there, it *needs to be*.